# Quirks of checkbox element when changing state

Tags: html

I'm not new to HTML, but I always get stuck on input element, below is some html:

```
<div><input id="firstInput" /></div>
<div><input id="secondInput" type="checkbox" /></div>
```

In the browser console, I typed those code:

```
let firstInput = document.getElementById('firstInput');
console.log(firstInput.value);
```

The first time it logs nothing. Then I typed "Hello" in the first input element and reissue `console.log(firstInput.value);`, and the output is:

> Hello

which is what I expected.

But for the second input, no matter if I check or uncheck, `console.log(secondInput.value);` always produces :

```
// first time the page finished loading, the input is unchecked by default,
// shouldn't it be off?
on

// always "on" no matter I check or uncheck.
on
```

why those quirks occurs?

Comment: For a checkbox to have a value you need to give it a hard-coded value attribute. E.g. `<input id="secondInput" type="checkbox" value="something" />`. Then you'd need to check whether it was checked or not. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the value property of a text input element, the value property of a checkbox is static by default. Its default value is 'on'. You are assuming that when unchecked the value property should dynamically change to 'off'. The lather is not documented anywhere. While you can add this behavior with JS, this is not a default behavior of the checkbox element.

Instead, as you probably already know since you are not new to HTML, the state of a checkbox is tracked in the 'checked' property. If the property is a boolean flag so is either true or false, checked or not checked.